# Energy displacement of a cylinder is at most $\pi r^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

I want to show that the energy displacement of $Z^{2n}(r)$ is at most $\pi r^2$.

In the [textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198504519) of Mcduff and Salamon they write that I should identify the two dimensional ball (with radius $r$) with a square of the same area, and then calculate Hofer's metric, $d_H(Id,\phi)$ where $\phi$ is a translation s.t $\phi(B^2(r)\times K) \cap (B^2(r)\times K)=\emptyset$.

I don't know how to calculate Hofer's metric, I mean it depends on the Hamiltonian here, and I don't know how does it look here?

Thanks in advance.
Edit: $K$ is a compact subset of $R^{2n-2}$.